# How can you know if a control is visible or invisible using Microsoft Active Accessibility

Tags: winapi

I noticed that AccExplorer (accessibility explorer) shows when controls are visible or invisible. How does it determine this? The api for MSAA does not have a IsVisible function. Any ideas?

Edit: IsWindowVisible does not actually tell you if it has been drawn or not. Even if something is 100% obscuring the window, IsWindowVisible can still return TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if a window (including controls) is visible with the standard [`IsWindowVisible()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633530%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Cool thanks. The problem was that I didn't know how to get the HWND from IAccessible pointer. I found WindowFromAccessibleObject so I'll be able to use IsWindowVisible.

Comment: IsWindowVisible() is not what I wanted because it returns true even when the object is not actually drawn onscreen. Is there a function that tells me if it actually was drawn or not?

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432336/how-to-find-a-windows-swshow-swhide-status/1432393#1432393) suggests using GetWindowPlacement().